# How to install dependency when JAR name differs from folder version name?

Tags: maven-2

I'm including a dependency from a custom Maven repository. The JAR I want to include is at the URL

```
http://mvn.example.org/repositories/org/apache/foo/foo/1.2.3-4/1.2.3-4-h2.jar
```

(Not the `-h2` at the end; it's important later.)

I've included `http://mvn.example.org/repositories` as a `<repository>` in my `settings.xml`, and set up my project's `pom.xml` to include

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3-4</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

However, when I try to `mvn install` with this setup, I get

```
Downloading: http://mvn.example.org/repositories/org/apache/foo/foo/1.2.3-4/1.2.3-4.jar
```

immediaqtely followed by a `BUILD FAILURE`, because that's not the URL of the JAR. Note that the *actual* URL, at the top of this question, has a `-h2` suffix to the version number, not present in the folder version number.

Seeing at the default assumption appears to be that the filanme of teh JAR matches the folder name, how can I tell Maven to pull a JAR whose version number filename is different from the containing folder filename?

Comment: I think this is just the `<classifier>` field.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, `<classifier>` was exactly the thing for it; thank you! Do you want to post an answer, or do you think this issue is too trivial to merit a question, and I should delete this? (As a Maven noob, I really didn't know the answer before, and your suggestion is exactly correct.)

Comment: Sure - it was an educated guess - but glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Maven classifier](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates).  You should be able to specify it with `<classifier>h2</classifier>`.